# Question about Arkham Knight dialog with Cat Woman and Batman

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

Pretty simple question.

> I noticed that after defeating the Riddler, Catwoman referred to Batman as Bruce. When did he reveal his identity to her?

I have played the other Batman games, but I did not play any of the catwoman parts of Arkham city.

> I finished Riddler BEFORE beating the game so I'm not sure how she knew batman was Bruce.

Was his identity revealed to her in the catwoman portion of the campaign in Arkham city?  Is there some other explanation?  Let's keep it to the canon of the games themselves (Arkham Asylum, City, Origins and Knight).

I would think the game developers would have had separate dialog for beating Riddler before and after the ending of the game, perhaps this was an oversight?

Comment: _Did_ she ever refer to him that way? I did get the collar off of her but haven't picked up all the riddles yet. I don't recall her ever calling him Bruce.  p.s., I don't think the spoiler warnings are necessary here.

Comment: I've edited so spoiler is just grayed out until you hover over it (waiting for review). @JeffMercado for me it's a spoiler, I haven't played that far and would kick someones ass if he would tell me something like that in my face^^

Comment: @Nitro.de: But seriously, what's to spoil? That someone knows the identity of Batman? If anything, the only thing to spoil is _how_ they came about that information. And those spoilers would be in the answers, not the question.  And that's why the spoiler markup exists.

Comment: Maybe it's expected that you beat the game _before_ beating the Riddler?  One of the riddler trophies can only be obtained in the second-to-last area, and it'd be pretty weird to go collect all the trophies after that, but before going to the final waypoint.

Comment: @JeffMercado what about the "after i defeated the riddler"? For me it's spoiler alert

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft That was what I was thinking with my last question there, and what I was sort of leaning towards.  I finished all the riddler stuff before the last story mission (which is where some of the potential spoilers come in).  And Nitro.de, thank you for adding spoiler tags!!! I need to learn how to use them.

Comment: @JeffMercado  I believe she called him that when you walk outside the orphanage.  I'll add an edit into the spoiler tags if you'd like to explain it in more detail why it could be a spoiler.

Answer (score 2):

So if you had gone through the main story, you would have learned that toward the end of the game:

> Scarecrow captures Gordon and Robin and threatens to kill them.  Batman surrenders himself to him in order to save them while Scarecrow intends to take off Batman's mask to reveal his identity to him and the world.
>  
>  Following these events, you're required to capture a requisite amount of villains in order to proceed.  I guess whenever Catwoman speaks out his name, you were supposed to be beyond this point in the game where she (and everyone) would have known.

Considering this is the longest of the sidequests, it's likely that most players would do this last and witnessed what happens in the story.

Comment: Yea I was thinking that could have been the case.  Interestingly enough, if you do the mission at Wayne tower after the ending, you get some different dialog from Fox (which surprises me that they didn't have different dialog for Cat Woman).  I'm sure are several different points in the game that have different dialog based on the order in which you do things.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the events of Arkham Knight occur six months (don't quote me on six months thou lol I know it's a few months) after Arkham City.. if you are a reader of any of the Batman (even Catwoman/Gotham City Sirens) comics, you come to discover that Selina Kyle aka Catwoman learns that Bruce Wayne is the Batman. Batman and Catwoman have had an ongoing love interest/sexual relationship while under masked identities, for quite some time.. Catwoman (Selina Kyle)  even eventually becomes pregnant by Batman (Bruce Wayne) and they have a daughter together, Helena Wayne (who eventually takes on the secret hero identity of, Huntress. Since the games are strongly based off of the comics, I'm pretty confident that with that few months between Arkham City and Knight, Catwoman came to discover Batman's true identity. Let's not forget that Catwoman does become a prominent member of the "Bat Family" so all Intel/Info that any other "member of the family" (Nightwing, Robin, Batgirl, Alfred, etc) would know, Catwoman would also know or come to know. So the events of Knight and Catwoman knowing Batman's true identity follows the events of the comic, shortly after Batman is unmasked as Bruce Wayne and he "goes M.I.A" Catwoman discovers she is pregnant by him.